# Storing an inner tube

Tags: storage, innertube

I got a spare inner tube with my bike, which is good.

I checked how it was packed and found it was sticking somewhat when I pulled it out of the box, which I can only imagine is bad.

Would it be an idea to put someething on the tube for storage, talcum powder maybe?

Comment: You can add talc if you want -- even though it may not be needed for storage, it's nice to have talc on the tube when installed (especially on a hot day when you're by the side of the road cursing).  But tubes are stored in the box like that for years with no apparent problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always carry a tube with me in my backpack on longer tours. I left it in the packet I bought it in, but only to protect it from being punctured by the other stuff I carry in the bag (eg a Leatherman and keys).

I doubt that this is necessary but with or without the carton, the tube fits perfectly at the bottom of my Camelback, and the bit of added weight doesn't freak me out, too.

There never was talkum on the tube, and it is a pretty expensive tube, so do not worry about that.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Unnecessary.
Longer answer: Talc would work.

Answer (score 0):

I carry patched ones as spares.  I store them purged of air and roll/folded up till the length is the same as my toolbag, then a wrap of masking tape to hold them together.  The toolbag is a flat grellow cloth bag about 140mm a side, with a velcro close, and I velcro-strap that to the top tube like this (end on view)

```
    O        <-- top tube
(T\_MP_/ST)  <-- Tools / minipump / spare tube
```

The toolbag forms a figure 8 almost shape, and is held on with three velcro straps.  The tube is surrounded only by cloth so no abrasion.  The pump is against the metal top tube.

I ride a road bike and a MTB so swap out the spare tube when changing bikes.  For a road trip, I carry a second new spare tube in its box, in the jersey pocket.  For some reason road tubes seem to puncture more often than MTB tubes.

Answer (score -1):

Talcum powder, baby powder even flour will keep it from sticking to other items or itself.

Long term storage you need to worry about the heat. if its older than a year i would worry about it dry rotting.

Comment: Flour is probably a bad choice as it will attract mold.  And f kept reasonably cool (and out of the sun) a tube in storage should last 5 years at least.  If they went bad in a year, bike shops wouldn't stock them.

Comment: not saying tons of flour, just a light rub.

Comment: In phoenix a tube left in a camelback will indeed not be long lasting.